# Splitting string separated by comma into array values in shell script?

Tags: arrays, string, shell, unix, awk

My data set(data.txt) looks like this [imageID,sessionID,height1,height2,x,y,crop]:

```
1,0c66824bfbba50ee715658c4e1aeacf6fda7e7ff,1296,4234,194,1536,0
2,0c66824bfbba50ee715658c4e1aeacf6fda7e7ff,1296,4234,194,1536,0
3,0c66824bfbba50ee715658c4e1aeacf6fda7e7ff,1296,4234,194,1536,0
4,0c66824bfbba50ee715658c4e1aeacf6fda7e7ff,1296,4234,194,1536,950
```

These are a set of values which I wish to use. I'm new to shell script :) I read the file line by line like this ,

```
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
string=($LINE)
# PROCESSING THE STRING
done
```

Now, in the code above, after getting the string, I wish to do the following :
1. Split the string into comma separated values.
2. Store these variables into arrays like imageID[],sessionID[].

I need to access these values for doing image processing using imagemagick.
 However, I'm not able to perform the above steps correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set -A` doesn't work for me (probably due to older BASH on OSX)

Posting an alternate solution using `read -a` in case someone needs it:

```
# init all your individual arrays here
imageId=(); sessionId=();

while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    imageId+=(${arr[0]})
    sessionId+=(${arr[1]})
done < input.csv

# Print your arrays
echo "${imageId[@]}"
echo "${sessionId[@]}"
```

Comment: Neat solution covering most of my requirements ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Couldn't you make the loop head `while IFS=, read -ra arr; do`, and get rid of the next line?

Comment: It seems that the initialization line `imageId=(); sessionId=();` is not necessary either. (Although it couldn't hurt!)

Answer (score 1):

```
oIFS="$IFS"; IFS=',' 
set -A str $string
IFS="$oIFS"

echo "${str[0]}";
echo "${str[1]}";
echo "${str[2]}";
```

you can split and store like this

have a look [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) for more on Unix arrays.

Comment: Ok, so your splitting the string and storing them in an array. How do I store the entities in different arrays . I want to create arrays of imageID's , sessionID's etc. Can you please modify your code ?

Comment: `set -A` doesn't work for me (no `-A` option to `set`). The page you link to uses `declare`.